# Scala - Flatten a List of Maps to Map

Tags: scala

I need to map a key to a map inside a list in Scala. In other words, I need to go from here:

```
  Map(k1 -> List(Map(k2 -> v2)))
```

And get this:

```
  Map(k1 -> Map(k2 -> v2))
```

This stuff is working but I am looking for something more efficient.

```
  val m1 = Map("k1" -> List(Map("k2" -> "v2")))
  val m2 = m1("k1").flatten.toMap
  val m3 = Map("k1" -> m2)
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What should happen if the list has multiple maps? Are the keys guarantee to never be the same? If not, what should happen with the duplicates?

Comment: It won't happen, the list is always coming with just one map inside. Yes, they are never going to be the same.

Comment: `m1.view.mapValues(_.head).toMap` should do the trick. However, it seems you are dealing with some JSON like data, I would recommend you to take a look at any of the excellent scala libraries. Also, the fact that you know that list will always have just one element seems like a design error, why it is a list then?

Comment: Yes, you are right indeed. I just posted a new question including more details if you want to check it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60860141/scala-convert-a-list-of-maps-to-a-map. Still, your answer fits this particular question so I decided to create a new post. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez said it is mostly something like

```
val maps = Map(k1 -> List(Map(k2 -> v2)))
def flattenMaps[K, V]: List[Map[K, V]] => Map[K, V] = ???
maps.mapValues(flattenMaps).toMap
```

The devil is in the details of your flattening logic:

```
// assumes that list always of size 1, loses random elements if bigger, blows up if size=0
def flattenMaps[K, V]: List[Map[K, V]] => Map[K, V] = _.head

// last wins
def flattenMaps[K, V]: List[Map[K, V]] => Map[K, V] = _.foldLeft(Map.empty[K, V]) {
  (bigMap, map) => bigMap ++ map
}

// first wins
def flattenMaps[K, V]: List[Map[K, V]] => Map[K, V] = _.foldLeft(Map.empty[K, V]) {
  (bigMap, map) => map ++ bigMap
}

// if you want to optimize for some reason, you can use builder instead
def flattenMaps[K, V]: List[Map[K, V]] => Map[K, V] = _.foldLeft(Map.newBuilder[K, V]) {
  (builder, map) =>
     builder ++= map
     builder
}.result

// or basically any other logic that makes sense and is defined for any input that type-checks
```

You should define some correct behavior in case your list will have more than one element (or none), otherwise you might be surprised one day if you'll forget about your assumptions.