# Scala - Convert a List of Maps to a Map

Tags: scala

I have a JSON string that I need to process and I am mapping it in the following manner:

```
val jsonMap = mapper.readValue[Map[String, Object]](jsonString)
```

My `jsonMap` contains the following value:

```
Map(k1 -> List(Map(k2 -> v2), Map(k3 -> v3))
```

The desired value for `newJsonMap` is:

```
 Map(k1 -> Map(k2 -> v2))
```

So in a nutshell, I want to convert the value of the `k1` key from a `List` to a `Map`. I first started to implement according to this question: [Scala - Flatten a List of Maps to Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60858646/scala-flatten-a-list-of-maps-to-map)

But then I realized that I was dealing with different datatypes, in this case `Map[String, Object]` which means I can't perform operations such as using the scala in-built `flatten` method to lists.

Is there any way I can convert this Map into a Scala Map so I can apply the necessary transformations to the JSON? Any thoughts on how I should proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which json library are you using? You must use that library or are you open to other options? What should be the type of the output? Can you give us an example json? Ate you sure you want a map of maps? Do you know the format you are parsing, if so why not defining some case classes that properly represent your model and parse your json into that?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, thanks for your help first of all. I am using jackson module to read the JSON into a Map[String, Object]. The main goal was to convert a json list into a json element (ie, replace "[ ]" for "{ }"). Example: json = { k1 = [ k2 = { ... } .. ] .. } into  { k1 = { k2 = { ... } .. } .. }. In this particular case, since I only need to do this conversion for an expected specific case the solution I found fits the problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is to do this

```
val jsonMap = mapper.readValue[Map[String, List[Map[String, String]]]](jsonString)
```

and then use the answer from the previous question.

If you want to do it by hand, something like this should work:

```
val map: Map[String, Map[String, String]] =
  jsonMap.collect {
    case (k, v: List[_]) =>
      val list: List[Map[String, String]] =
        v.collect {
          case m: Map[_, _] =>
            m.collect {
              case (k: String, v: String) =>
                k -> v
            }
        }
      k -> list.headOption.getOrElse(Map.empty)
  }
```

This will ignore any elements in `Object` that are not the required type. Nested `collect` expressions are required because type erasure prevents matching on a nested type in one operation.

This is assuming that you want the `head` of the `List[Map]` inside the `Object`, but it should be clear how to change this to a different transformation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I didnt use it this away though, but your function helped me understanding the problem!